# Entity Framework Map() property alternate in EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-model-builder

I am migrating my project from Entity Framework to EF Core 6 but now I am stuck at this point.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblStoreGroup>()
            .HasMany(e => e.tblUsers)
            .WithMany(e => e.tblStoreGroups)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("tblBridgeUserGroup")
                       .MapLeftKey("GroupID")
                       .MapRightKey("username"));
```

Because the `Map()` property is not available in EF Core, can someone please provide a solution for this code?

I am a beginner in Entity Framework.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `UsingEntity`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<tblStoreGroup>()
    .HasMany(p => p.tblUsers)
    .WithMany(p => p.tblStoreGroups)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "tblBridgeUserGroup",
        j => j
            .HasOne<tblUser>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("username"),
        j => j
            .HasOne<tblStoreGroup>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("GroupID"));
```

See [Joining relationships configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#joining-relationships-configuration) section of the docs.